# Discrete Math Modulus Beginner Direct Proof

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

I am having trouble with a direct proof in my discrete mathematics class. It is about modularity.

The statement I am supposed to prove is, "If a is congruent to b mod 12, then a is congruent to b mod 6."

I understand that there are 3 things that are immediately known when doing a direct proof pertaining to modulus.

1. a = 12k + b
2. a = 12q + r
   b = 12n + r
3. a - b = 12m

With that being said, I have been staring at this problem for a couple of hours, and I know the solution is probably staring right at me in the face, but I have been unable to find it. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How did you know that $a - b = 12m$ for some integer $m$? And what would it mean (in the style of the above) to show that $a \equiv b \pmod 6$?

Comment: I was under the impression (from simply the definition of modulus), that the statement a - b = 12m. Or more generically, a - b = nm. This could be derived from a = mn + b.

Comment: Right! What I'm getting at, is that if you need to know that $a-b = 6n$, for some integer $n$, and you already know $a-b = 12m$ fornsome integer $m$... well, find a way to write $12m$ as $6 \cdot \rm something$ and you're done

Answer (score 0):

"$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo 12" means that $r=\frac1{12}(a-b)$
is an integer.

"$a$ is congruent to $b$ modulo 6" means that $s=\frac16(a-b)$
is an integer.

So you need to prove that if $r$ is an integer, then $s$ is an integer.

What is the relationship between $r$ and $s$?

Comment: So basically what you are saying is take the r, and multiply it by 2, so I would have 2r, and then set 2r = s?

Comment: @Conner yes, $s=2r$. Is twice an integer always an integer?

Comment: Yes, I would think so, since they are both integers. Thank you for your help!